# Shell script substring till space

Tags: linux, bash

I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me how I can extract all characters up to the first space or tab character after having tested that what follows the space/tab is another specified substring?  For example a file containing

```
php server-side
asp server-side
css client-side
html client-side
golang server-side
```

when read line-by-line could be used to generate the string

```
php asp golang
```

i.e. with the lines ending client-side dropped out altogether and the lines containing server-side truncated at the space.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This command will do the trick,

```
grep "server-side" filename|cut -d ' ' -f1|tr '\n' ' '
```

**Explanation** as follows;

```
grep "server-side" filename
```

It will capture only lines matched with the string server-side.

```
cut -d ' ' -f1
```

`cut` commmand will cut first column of the table by delimiter space.

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

`tr` command will make all new line character replaced with a space.

**Output** will be exactly what OP mentioned in question(requirement):

```
php asp golang
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer over the others since you offer a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep "server-side" FILE_NAME | awk '{print $1}'
```

Explanation:
grep "server-side" FILE_NAME can filter out those client side entries.
Then awk '{print $1}' can print only the first row of the text.

Comment: If you explained what this commands does - the answer would look much better

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to loop over the tokens in a shell loop anyway, the shell has whitespace splitting built in.

```
sep=''
while read -r lang feat; do
    case $feat in "client-side" ) continue;; esac
    printf '%s%s' "$sep" "$lang"   # replace this with something actually useful?
    sep=' '
done <<____HERE
    php server-side
    asp server-side
    css client-side
    html client-side
    golang server-side
____HERE
```

Comment: thank you.  Skynet's answer is good enough for my present needs but I am voting up yours as well since it is bound to be useful in a different context.

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n 's/[[:space:]]\+server-side$//p' file
php
asp
golang
```

Pass the output to `tr` command is you want a folded output.

```
sed -n 's/[[:spacee$//p' ri | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep server-side foo.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | paste -s -
```